# Function to find varying strings

Tags: r, string, user-defined-functions

I need to do the following as a homework assignment and I am struggling to find the right answer:

Write a function, `find.names()` that takes two arguments: `df`, a data frame, with
columns name and text; and `str`, a string. Your function should find all the Wikipedia entries
(in `df$text`) that contain the word `str`, ignoring the cases of characters, and return the corresponding
names of individuals (in `df$names`), as a string vector sorted in alphabetical order. For
example, `find.names(wiki, "Carnegie Mellon")` should return `c("Alan Fletcher (composer)",
"John Tarnoff", "Joshua Bloch")`.

Here is my starting code:

```
find.names = function(df,str){
grep("str|Str", df$text, value=TRUE)
return(df$names)
}
```

Does `str` need to be in quotes? I'm unsure how to put that. Or a `for` loop?  I try the sample listed, `find.names(wiki, "Carnegie Mellon)` and it returns `NULL`. I know I am missing something.

Thanks in advance for you help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can make use of `ignore.case = TRUE` in `grep`

```
find.names = function(df, str){
     df$name[grep(str, df$text, ignore.case = TRUE)]

   }

find.names(wiki, "Carnegie Mellon")
```

Comment: This is really helpful. The only problem left is that with you code, it returns df$text, when I want it to return df$name. That is, I want it to return the first column associated with that row of data, not the second. My initial attempt: `return(df$name) ` still returns `NULL`.

Comment: @Bkk  Thanks for the comments.  In fact, I was a bit confused by the `grep` sitting idle in your function.  It returns an index and that can be used for subsetting 'name'.  Updated the answer.  I hope that is what you meant

Comment: Thank you! I did have to remove `value=TRUE` to get the df$name column, but this works.

Comment: @Bkk Yeah, sorry it was my mistake for not checking all the arguments.  thank you